# How to read content of pass.pkpass file and send in text/xml restfull webservice response

Tags: php, ios, web-services, passbook, wallet

I impleted https://github.com/tschoffelen/php-pkpass to generate pkpass.

I integrated in backed restfull api which send response in text/xml content type.

I am trying to read .pkpass file in backed and send in api response as below that could be decoded by ios app and use this pkpass.

but using file-get-content we are not geting valid content that could be sent as string. this works fine if we use this to dowload file from web browser.

Is there anything that I am missing to read content of .pkpass file.

```
public function create($output = false)
    {
        $paths = $this->getTempPaths();
        // Creates and saves the json manifest
        if(!($manifest = $this->createManifest())) {
            $this->clean();

            return false;
        }

        // Create signature
        if($this->createSignature($manifest) == false) {
            $this->clean();

            return false;
        }

        if($this->createZip($manifest) == false) {
            $this->clean();

            return false;
        }

        // Check if pass is created and valid
        if(!file_exists($paths['pkpass']) || filesize($paths['pkpass']) < 1) {
            $this->sError = 'Error while creating pass.pkpass. Check your ZIP extension.';
            $this->clean();

            return false;
        }

        // Get contents of generated file
        $file = file_get_contents($paths['pkpass']);
        $size = filesize($paths['pkpass']);
        $name = basename($paths['pkpass']);

        // Cleanup
        //$this->clean();

        // Output pass
        if($output == true) {
            $fileName = $this->getName() ? $this->getName() : $name;
            if(!strstr($fileName, '.')) {
                $fileName .= '.pkpass';
            }
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $fileName . '"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T'));
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . $size);
            @ob_end_flush();
            set_time_limit(0);
            echo $file;

            return true;
        }
        return $file;
    }
```

method call

```
$pk_pass =  $pass->create('false');

$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$xml .= '<root>';
$xml .= '<pass>'.$pk_pass.'</pass>';
$xml .= '</root>';
```

Response I get as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <pass>PKX��L����l   &
    signature͖{8�[�����0��F�J�=.!G�%��k:��1���L��R��"�NT��J���)���t��n_�')Gw���P�������1����Z{�{��~{)���$�3�-R�eR���4a"kF-"�b��0���?B2))��A
�`X��e�������nSv�2�&)$�5*�т��Z`�\�j`W��lыK#����R]�dR���b�Atcla�y|����`SD,WHv.rk����aMteD�HM!Wn1y�(��Ñ큭�ؐ��Dt�&I%��1X�\ӝy��!Hc�"�h<��`��<W��QYl�G�Pd[`=�a�~�!10����m�;nS!Q���    

���     
$���8i��{{��z����xy��ݾ�)�B��Î�J
i*!z,,� �+7��W���=�1�ì���N��Ч�!>��~{�����p�����������[ޥ)����\����(������U��E�[���,jM_�+��ZU��wV��
5ϰ�.Ģ�s�V�jh�}������W<�Q�x�nB��J�O&܏��9���������v����t`��qC�Gb_]8��pb_�9|ۗ[Zb�����?r)���ك�c��+/��]��%ZTt2��ò��l{�[�t��E������!,b�i&����J��Lh� %�T
�)�\8�J�P>4A��n����zjU
��́gg�x�^�,mNU3��*�&K`�QP�S$�/���ф|E���;V�b1]��Д�@DK!�V H&���FW��d,�� ������S�hK i�d�,Ԡ!9�$9�¥1�Hb��,!��)�Dj�CrO BFB�fCH��h�h�'�a�\�|ċ����St��!� \:����Y�ń8m2̿؈�C|�&-��5��B�h�5E�+��
        <y@�����Ӡ�O1A�@>o�^�2�Q��TTh����L��% �=f�u�ڑ���.4�N��(4mTJ���p��D�Q�J2���Nm�A�h�����&~�ƿ�J^^�ݔ����`���
����

                                                                                                                                                </pass>
                                                                                                                                            </root>
```

Comment: Show us your code or it will be pretty hard for us to know if you missed something. Note: The pass-file is most likely a binary file, which means that you need to encode the content using base64 or similar before you can send it as a string to an API.

Comment: Added method that return response.

Comment: $file = file_get_contents($paths['pkpass']); return content but that can not be handeled in api response.

Comment: Like I said, you need to encode the data before sending it to an API. `$file = base64_encode($file);`. Then the API needs to decode it, using `$content = base64_decode($theEncodedData);`. XML is a text-format. You can't send binary data in XML.

Comment: Where are you making the API call? I only see you outputting the contents?

Comment: thanks in base64_decode($theEncodedData); I got some reponse. lets see this can be used to use as passbook.

Answer (score 0):

@praveen I had done this before few days ago but not with xml. 
I just tell you provide url intend of .pkpass content.
like http://example.com/pass/xx where xx is id/serial of that pass. 
which is process in php and prepare pass with appropriate content. when someone hit this url fresh generate .pkpass.